# tkinter: check modified

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a newbie python/tkinter programmer!
I am displaying a text widget for the user to use as a barebones editor.

Is it possible to check if the user modified it in any way, so that I know if it necessary a savefile step?

thanks!

alessandro

Comment: You could always create a handler that sets a flag on change: `instance.bind('<Event>', lambda event: setattr(event.widget, 'modified', True)`

Comment: let me know if my suggestion worked for you. There are other possibilities if this doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to use the [`Text.edit_modified()`](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.Text-class.html#edit_modified) method. A simple usage example:

```
>>> import Tkinter
>>> root = Tkinter.Tk()
>>> frame = Tkinter.Frame(root)
>>> text = Tkinter.Text(frame)
>>> text.pack()
>>> frame.pack()
>>> text.edit_modified()
0
>>> text.insert('1.0', 'some text')
>>> text.edit_modified()
1
>>> text.edit_modified(False)
''
>>> text.edit_modified()
0
```